# can i fade in and out carousel image onclick in framer-motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

i have an array with src imgs

and the src in the `<img src={imgs[index]} />` changes depends on the `[Index]` variable

and i wanted to fade in and out the image when i click on the buttons

code:

```
const [Index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const carouselHandler = (i) => {
  setIndex(i);
};
```

```
<div>
  <div>
    <img src={imgs[Index].img} />
  </div>
  {/* indicators */}
  {[1, 2, 3].map((text, i) => (
    <button
      style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", margin: 4 }}
      onClick={() => {
        carouselHandler(i);
      }}
      key={i}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  ))}
</div>
```

i tried `useAnimation()` but i just couldnt do much

my brain hurts